# Data separation by particular rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am relatively new to using Matlab and I don't have much knowledge about programming either. For a project I am working on currently I need to process a lot of data which is logged using the following format.

```
$GPRMC,202124.985,V,,,,,,,091112,,,N*44
2038,4674,4667,5593,3379
2087,5133,5111,6084,3372
2138,5134,5114,6080,3376
2188,5133,5114,6084,3377
2238,5130,5113,6084,3410
2287,5134,5113,6080,3416
2337,5133,5110,6080,3417
2387,5133,5110,6084,3416
2438,5130,5113,6081,3396
2487,5132,5110,6080,3410
$GPRMC,202125.985,V,,,,,,,091112,,,N*45
2985,5130,5113,6085,3988
3035,5130,5118,6084,4541
3085,5138,5113,6082,5186
3135,5130,5114,6081,6001
3185,5134,5110,6084,6311
3234,5134,5113,6084,6319
3284,5131,5114,6084,6316
3339,5131,5110,6084,6260
3389,5130,5114,6080,6178
3438,5134,5110,6085,6077
$GPRMC,202126.985,V,,,,,,,091112,,,N*46
3942,5131,5114,6085,5916
3992,5130,5110,6084,5917
4042,5133,5110,6084,5950
4091,5131,5114,6080,5996
4142,5134,5114,6085,6062
4192,5134,5114,6084,6129
4242,5134,5110,6080,6150
4291,5130,5110,6079,6186
4341,5130,5110,6089,6246
4391,5130,5118,6083,6266
```

It continues like this until the end of the file. What I want to do is to be able to separate the data such that, all the '$GPRMC' strings (rows) are listed together as text (not separated) in one file or array while all the other rows (numerical) listed together in one file array (comma separated is desirable). Is it even possible? If it is than can you please give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean by separated or not separated.  If you copy the text you posted into some file like `testf.dat`, a simple script like this using `fopen`, `fprintf`, and `fgets` might be what you're looking for:

```
infile = fopen('testf.dat');                                                        
outf1 = fopen('GPRMC.dat','w');                                                 
outf2 = fopen('nums.dat','w');                                                  

tline = fgets(infile);                                                          
while ischar(tline)                                                             
    if tline(1:6) == '$GPRMC'                                                   
        fprintf(outf1,tline);                                                   
    else                                                                        
        fprintf(outf2,tline);                                                   
    end                                                                         
    tline = fgets(infile);                                                      
end                                                                             

fclose(infile);                                                                 
fclose(outf1);                                                                  
fclose(outf2);
```

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your reply. This is precisely what I want but there is a glitch, may be you can help figure it out. When I run your code, it creates two new .dat files as intended. After that the first line ($GPRMC line) gets written to the GPRMC.dat file and the program stops with the following error....    **??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions**...     I also tried removing the first $GPRMC line from the original testf.dat file so that the first line (and following 9 lines) are numerical data. This time the 10 numerical lines get transfered to nums.dat with the same error.

Comment: Hi, I changed the code slightly, for the if statement I used if tline(1) == '$'... this time no errors and it works perfectly.... so thanks a lot.   Another problem I have now is it is leaving blank lines in num.dat file between 10 numeic lines. Can I remove those?